# Server to Server ssh via Private Key -- Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, ssh, public-key-encryption, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I know this question is from the list of probably most downvoted questions but nonetheless have been stuck on it since morning, so worth a try getting a positive response from the community. I have already went through various already questions asked and their solutions, but guess it's not working.

I am following the https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/deployment/composer-npm-deploy.html to write deploy script from gitlab runner to my server. Hence, the runner (ubuntu/docker based) needs to transfer the files to my server and because the runner is dynamic *(In this case - both are droplets)*

- I am using the private key of my server
- Placing the private key in the runner by running

> eval $(ssh-agent -s)
>
> nano /root/.ssh/id_rsa_sid (pasted the private key content from my server (.ssh/id_rsa))
>
> ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa_sid
>
> Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa_sid (/root/.ssh/id_rsa_sid)

Now, when I do ssh -v root@serverip, I am getting Permission denied (publickey). *(I tried -i key file path flag as well -- same result)*

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:~/.ssh# ssh -v -i id_rsa_sid root@serverip
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 128.xxx.xxx.xxx [128.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file id_rsa_sid type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file id_rsa_sid-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 128.199.253.228:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/El3UFF60r6/qNAwvfyIzx6Cf6N2YuXed/UU5QWEP1Q
debug1: Host '128.199.253.228' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa_sid
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa_sid
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

As you can see, it trying the file both as public key and private key but failing.

I went to the server for logs:

> cat /var/log/auth.log

```
Jul  5 13:13:16 docker-512mb-sgp1-01 sshd[2371]: Connection closed by 128.yyy.yyy.yy port 43292 [preauth]
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or if you may - point me to right resource.

Comment: And what does say `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server side?

Comment: You're supposed to share the *public key*, id_rsa.pub. Never share private keys.

Comment: @BjornA.Refer to link in the question. It says to add private key. What to do now?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs do I need to add the server private key to it's authorized_keys. Don't we use it to put the public keys. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me *(who came looking for an answer here)*

Did a bit of troubleshooting and found it to be rather a silly mistake.

Add the server's public key to it's authorized keys file. That will do :-)

Thanks